# Bootstrap LESS variable context for separate files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, less

The Eclipse LESS plugin doesn't like that the bootstrap LESS files reference variables in other files, and so it gives errors like '*The variable '@line-height-computed' is undefined in this context.*'. Although, I got the plugin to compile the LESS source successfully by compiling the main bootstrap.less file which imports all of the other LESS files. This works because while compiling, the variables are in the context of the main bootstrap.less files. I tried setting the validation configuration for the plugin but that didn't work.
So I guess my question is: Is there a way to fix these errors? Or do I have to live with them even though I am able to compile fine?

Comment: Try Aptana IDE, an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable these errors in the **LESS/Validation Preferences** by unchecking:

- Undeclared mixins
- Undeclared variables

[image: LESS/Validation Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap LESS code has been split into different files. Variables are defined in the variables.less, so you can edit them all on a single place. To compile Bootstrap you should compile the main bootstrap.less file indeed.
You can not compile a single file cause these files depend on the other files (mostly variables.less and mixins.less). Since version 3.2. also the mixins are split into different files. mixins.less imports this mixins files.

To compile a single file you can try to import the variables and mixins at the beginning of the file:

```
@import "variables"
@import "mixins"
```